# add an item in table of contents with no page number and hyperlink

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, tocloft

I wanted to add a separate line saying "CHAPTER" in toc, but I don't want it to have a page number and to link anywhere. My current code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTERS}{}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Some section 1}

\chapter{Some chapter 2}
\section{Some section 2}

\end{document}
```

In this way, there is no page number, but "CHAPTERS" is still clickable. How could I remove the hyperlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\addtocontents` instead of `\cftaddtitleline`.

```
% titlelineprob.tex  SE 564030
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTERS}{}
\addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{CHAPTERS}\par}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Some section 1}

\chapter{Some chapter 2}
\section{Some section 2}

\end{document}
```